# Angular constantly growing store

Tags: angular, typescript, redux, memory-leaks, ngrx

I have noticed strange behavior in my test application, whenever i'm overriding my store with new array it seems like old state is still in memory (only recent bar should be in blue)
[image]

For test purposes i'm dispatching load action 10 times every 5 seconds.

```
  ngOnInit() {
    setInterval(() => {
      for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        this.store.dispatch(CharacterActions.getCharacters());
      }
    }, 5000);
  }
```

This is how my store looks like

```
export interface CharacterState {
  characters: Character[];
}

export const initialState: CharacterState = {
  characters: [],
};

export const characterReducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(CharacterActions.getCharactersSuccess, (state, { characters }) => ({
    ...state,
    characters: [...characters],
  }))
);
```

And character class

```
import { Weapon } from "./weapon";

export class Character {
    name: string;
    surname: string;
    private weapons: Weapon[];

    constructor(name: string, surname: string, weapons?: Weapon[]) {
        this.weapons = weapons ?? [];
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    public getWeapons(): Weapon[] {
        return this.weapons;
    }

    public addWeapon(weapon: Weapon): void {
        this.weapons.push(weapon);
    }

    public upgradeWeapon(name: string, value: number) {
        this.weapons.find(x => x.name === name.toLowerCase())?.upgrade(value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok i think it's working for version `@ngrx/store@14.2.0` for every higher it's not.
[image]

Comment: If your image contains essential information, please consider adding it to your answer as text too, as images hosting may expire.